# Filling a field in a layer using a spatial relation with another layer/shapefile automaticly?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-processing

My question was kind of answered by @mgri at [Filling a field in a layer using a spatial relation with another layer/shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233784/filling-a-field-in-a-layer-using-a-spatial-relation-with-another-layer-shapefile/233794#233794)

If you have read that part, then I no longer need to repeat myself on this one. If not I will keep it simple by illustrate:

[image]

Just to note: I know how to create the process by using the following steps:

1. Create a buffer layer of my "bomen" point shapefile with "Fixed Buffer distance" tool.
2. Join this buffer layer to the straten shapefile and saving the records that intersect. Creating a new layer/shapefile in the process
3. Join the new merged layer/shapefile to the "Bomen" bomenschapefile and saving that overwriting the old shapefile.

How do I automate this so that when a new object is created in the "bomen" shapefile, this process gets executed?