# Preventing a new/duplicate column to bo created in a spatial join in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I wanted to have an common (between two shapefile's) column filled in by certain criteria by creating a buffer first (based on that criteria) and the do some spatial join steps. However I noticed that the column's of the shapefile were added to my new buffer shapefile after doing the spatial join to the buffer.

I assumed that, because the columns did not share a name this was a problem. So I made sure to that the name of respective columns were to same. I redid the proces, but the same thing happened, so I deleted all fields that were not necessary (after making a copy of the shapefile). I redid it again and the same thing happened.

To illustrate
[image]

How can I prevent this, what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: Go here if you want to know what I originally wanted: [Filling a field in a layer using a spatial relation with another layer/shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233784/filling-a-field-in-a-layer-using-a-spatial-relation-with-another-layer-shapefile)

Comment: As far as I know Spatial Joins in QGIS always create new columns, there is no way to update existing columns using a Spatial Join.

Comment: ....Oke then can you give me a another suggestion. I can simply solve this by deleting the street column. Then do the spatial join, however since this column wil be linked to another calculation, I sadly cannot do that.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I do not really get what you want. You could also copy the data from column "Straat_1" to column "Straat" and then you delete "Straat_1". Which Spatial Join Tool are you using?

Comment: please check here this is what I originally wanted http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233784/filling-a-field-in-a-layer-using-a-spatial-relation-with-another-layer-shapefile. It is join attribute based on location that I use.

Comment: Well, a classical Spatial Join. As I said I do not think that filling the column with a Spatial Join is possible. Leave the original "Straat" column inside the shapefile, do the spatial join, copy the data from the new column and delete the new column.

Comment: Is there something else I can use then, based on the link I gave you what can you recommend?

Comment: As commented before, my thoughts are for you to move away from the shapefile to and from PostGIS interaction, and use the offline editing plugin to convert the PostGIS database to a local spatialite file that can be used in the field and then be synced with PostGIS. One of the main advantages of a database is that you can use scripts to do the things that you are trying to do. If I am understanding things correctly.

Comment: Oke thank you I will ask other questions in relation to this offline editing. If i may but not here.

Comment: In my post to your question [Filling a field in a layer using a spatial relation with another layer/shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233784/filling-a-field-in-a-layer-using-a-spatial-relation-with-another-layer-shapefile): instead of _merging_ in Step 5, right-click the original layer and go to `Properties > Joins`. Here you can join the attributes of both your original and spatial layer but you can choose which fields you want joined. Then use the **Field Calculator** to create or update fields whilst copying over the values from the joined layer. Finally, remove the join.